# Image setSmallSourceUrl is Deprecated?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

To add an image to a StandardCard card, I set

Image image = new Image();

where Image comes from com.amazon.speech.ui.  Various blogs then say to use 
image.setSmallSourceUrl and image.setLargeSourceUrl to set the URLs of the image but these two methods seem to have been deprecated in alexa-skills-kit-1.4.0.

Furthermore, there seem to be two (incompatible) Image classes in play.  One in com.amazon.speech.ui.Image and another in com.amazon.speech.speechlet.interfaces.display.element.Image.

1) What is the correct way of adding the two images to a StandardCard?
2) Which of the two image types does StandardCard want?

Answer (score 0):

Below shows the format of response,

```js
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {"type":"PlainText","text":"output speech"},
    "card": {
      "type": "Standard",
      "title": "Title",
      "text": "sample test",
      "image": {
        "smallImageUrl": "YourSmallImage here",
        "largeImageUrl": "YourLarge image here"
      }
    }
  }
```

You can provide images in the following formats:

```
JPEG
PNG
```

smallImageUrl recommended size is 720w x 480h (in pixels) and largeImageUrl recommended size is 1200w x 800h (in pixels)